# (Python) Splitting string only on single instance of delimiter

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to extract numeric values from text strings that use dashes as delimiters, but also to indicate negative values:

```
"1.3"          # [1.3]
"1.3-2-3.9"    # [1.3, 2, 3.9]
"1.3-2--3.9"   # [1.3, 2, -3.9]
"-1.3-2--3.9"  # [-1.3, 2, -3.9]
```

At the moment, I'm manually checking for the "--" sequence, but this seems really ugly and prone to breaking.

```
def get_values(text):
    return map(lambda s: s.replace('n', '-'), text.replace('--', '-n').split('-'))
```

I've tried a few different approaches, using both the str.split() function and re.findall(), but none of them have quite worked.

For example, the following pattern should match all the valid strings, but I'm not sure how to use it with findall:

```
r"^-?\d(\.\d*)?(--?\d(\.\d*)?)*$"
```

Is there a general way to do this that I'm not seeing? Thanks!

Comment: I like your `get_values`, actually. a one-liner that is easy to read and does hide the bad design of the underlying data structure well.

Comment: Actually, I just realized that get_values() breaks when the string starts with a dash. it ends up giving ('', '1.3', '2', '-3.9') for the 4th example. It's a fixable, but it would involve another layer of kludge...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to split with this pattern with a lookbehind:

```
(?<=[0-9])-
```

(An hyphen preceded by a digit)

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split('(?<=[0-9])-', text)
```

With this condition, you are sure to not be after the start of the string or after an other hyphen.

Comment: @Tiro: happy for you! But take a look at iCodez solution that is faster.

Answer (score 2):

@CasimiretHippolyte has given a very elegant Regex solution, but I would like to point out that you can do this pretty succinctly with just a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter), and [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
>>> def get_values(text):
...    it = iter(text.split("-"))
...    return [x or "-"+next(it) for x in it]
...
>>> get_values("1.3")
['1.3']
>>> get_values("1.3-2-3.9")
['1.3', '2', '3.9']
>>> get_values("1.3-2--3.9")
['1.3', '2', '-3.9']
>>> get_values("-1.3-2--3.9")
['-1.3', '2', '-3.9']
>>>
```

Also, if you use [`timeit.timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit), you will see that this solution is quite a bit faster than using Regex:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>>
>>> # With Regex
>>> def get_values(text):
...     import re
...     return re.split('(?<=[0-9])-', text)
...
>>> timeit('get_values("-1.3-2--3.9")', 'from __main__ import get_values')
9.999720634885165
>>>
>>> # Without Regex
>>> def get_values(text):
...     it = iter(text.split("-"))
...     return [x or "-"+next(it) for x in it]
...
>>> timeit('get_values("-1.3-2--3.9")', 'from __main__ import get_values')
4.145546989910741
>>>
```

Comment: For this particular project, speed isn't a major factor (at least, not for this component), but this is good to know. Thanks for the alternate approach!